# How to atomically add a sequentially increasing id to a set of name/id pairs

Tags: mongodb

I need to assign sequentially increasing ids to a set of names. This boils to:

A field that contains the next id to be generated: `curId`

A set `myset` containing the name/value pair, where the value is the id and the name is the name

The problem:

I need to atomically:
1. Check if `myset` contains 'name'. If not,
2. Generate a new id using $inc.
3. Insert the name/id pair in myset.

I can't find a way to do this in mongodb, at least without introducing race conditions. Suggestions welcome.

**Update**

Sample document (what it should look like).

Before adding 'c':

```
{

    "mySet": [
        {
            "name": 'a',
            "value" : 1
        },
        {
            "name": 'b',
            "value" : 2
        }
    ]
}
```

After adding 'c'. 3 is returned since that is the id assigned to 'c'.

```
{

    "mySet": [
        {
            "name": 'a',
            "value" : 1
        },
        {
            "name": 'b',
            "value" : 2
        },
        {
            "name": 'c',
            "value" : 3
        }
    ]
}
```

Trying to add 'c' again. 
Nothing happens since 'c' is already present. But '3' is returned since that is the id for 'c'.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include example before and after documents?

Comment: done. i removed the counter field since i guess i can use a separate counter collection to generate sequentially increasing ids

Comment: see my answer: as it turns out, you must store the counter in the same document so that its increment and pushing a used value can happen atomically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way to do it, it involves maintaining the counter corresponding to the nextId to be used *inside* the document with this set, and it involves a simple find query and an update.  Starting with an empty document:

```
{ 
  "curId": 1,
  "mySet" : [  ]
}
```

The process that wants to add the next "name" (variable Name) does the following two operations:

```
var Name = "a";
var curId = db.coll.findOne({"mySet.name":{"$ne":Name}},{"_id":0,"curId":1}).curId;

/* curId variable is now 1 */
var result = db.coll.update(
    { "mySet.name" : {"$ne":Name}, "curId":curId },
    { "$push": {"mySet" : {"name":Name,"value":curId} }, "$inc":{"curId":1} }
);

if (result.nModified == 0) {
   print("We lost - someone else must have gotten there first");
}
```

The critical parts here are:

1. the find query and the update query are conditional on `Name` not already being in `mySet` array "names".
2. the update query also contains the previously read value of `curId` to ensure that no other thread has updated the record since we read it.
3. the `curId` field is only incremented on successful `$push` to array *not* on previous read of `curId` - until we have successfully used the `curId` value available, we don't want to increment it.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.counter.insert({"_id": "myCollectionName", "count": 1})
```

This creates a counter collection. Run a find and modify to increment it. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/ This operation is atomic and won't cause a race condition. Use the result as your new id.

EDIT: My apologies,  didn't realize all 3 needed to be atomic. Use $push (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/). This operation does not guarantee that the array will be in order (id of 2 may make it into the array before id 1) however the potential to losing an element of the array like you wold with a straight update is non existent. Use $push in conjuction with findandmodify (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) which is atomic as well.

Comment: as commented above, that only makes an atomic counter, i still need to perform the 3 operations listed in my question, all atomically

Comment: I've updated the answer. See $push and findAndModify() combination. Your generation of a new ID will have to be a completely separate operation, but it in itself will be atomic

Comment: $push will add it to array without checking if it exists. also that would mean generating an id each time even if the element is present. could you give a code sample of what you are describing

Comment: Your findAndModify would include a check to make sure it does not exist.

Comment: so currently what you have written is more of a 'food for thought'. Provide a concrete code sample which does what you say and i will accept this as the answer.

Comment: you don't need findAndModify - you just need a single update (which is atomic) that both pushes and increments the counter.  This is why you cannot store the counter in a separate collection.